# What is 'task' in F#?

Tags: f#

```
             let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
             task {
                 let connection =
                     let ipEndPoint = IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)
                     EventStoreConnection.Create(ipEndlPoint)
                 do! connection.ConnectAsync()
                 return connection
             }
```

For *task* I get:

> The value of constructor 'task' is not defined.

So, what is this and how can I define it?

Comment: A task computation builder: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/581 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions

Comment: This code is likely to be referencing one of the (many) TaskBuilder implementations available.  At some point a standard version will likely by added to F# (see @Caramirel's link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the question is in the context of Logary, which gets the `task` computation builder from the `TaskBuilder.fs` NuGet package (as we can see from [Paket references](https://github.com/logary/logary/blob/master/paket.dependencies)). The `TaskBuilder.fs` project [is available here with some documentation](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs).

So, `task` is a variable that represents an instance of the `TaskBuilder` computation builder. This is an [F# computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions), which lets you create computations that create the .NET `Task<T>` type as the result. Inside the computation expression, you can use `let!` and `do!` for the same purpose as `await` in C#, that is for waiting until some asynchronous operation completes (without blocking a thread):

```
task {
  do! Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Enter a filename:")
  let! name = Console.In.ReadLineAsync()
  use file = File.CreateText(name)
  for i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100) do
    do! file.WriteLineAsync(String.Format("hello {0}", i))
  do! Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Done")
  return name
}
```

Here, `WriteLineAsync` and `ReadLineAsync` are .NET methods that return `Task` and we can use them as if they were returning just `string` or `unit`.

It is also worth adding that Logary is perhaps not the easiest piece of F# code to look into. It is very clever and nice, but relies on the HOPAC concurrency library which requires a fair bit of background knowledge and uses a number of fancy operators, which can make code quite tricky to understand. So if you are relatively new to F#, understanding HOPAC code might be a bit of a struggle!